# Is database change notification better than trigger?

Tags: c#, .net, oracle, wcf, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing an application using Oracle database and WCF/WebAPI service. The service should know about changing certain table in database. I surfed the web and found a technology in Oracle RDBMS named "Database change notification" which I think is really the thing I need in such situation. But my team lead holding me to use trigger for that purpose.

Could somebody explain pros and cons of each technology for notifying service about table changes?

I want to track `insert`,`update`,`delete` operations on table, the way I plan to notify service is using `UTL_HTTP` package to invoke service's methods.

Thanks in advance!

---

**Update:** Notifications should be sent as soon as possible. So any ways that work periodically (for instance, put the notifications in a queue and handle them with oracle job every 1 minute) wouldn't fit.

Answer (score 1):

Database triggers are good for complex default values or complex data validation. Don't use them for application logic like sending messages. When there will be any problem with http connection, you won't be able to change your data.
Anyway, you can create notification queue (using for example new table or Oracle Queue) and fill it using triggers, that could be safe. Then write a job, which will query this queue and send notifications.

When you look at Database change notification concept (see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_dcn.htm#BGBDBAIJ, fig. 13.2), you see, that it uses the same approach.

So I vote for Database change notification. You need not use triggers, just register objects and write notification procedure code.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I forgot to mention that the service should receive notifications from database as soon as possible. So I expect your approach using notification queue with job (as I expect it periodical) doesn't fit such needs?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your team lead is thinking of DBMS_ALERT, which uses a trigger to send table event signals.  This could work in your scenario (given that we don't know the details of what you're trying to achieve ).  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_alert.htm#ARPLS351).

However, Database Change Notification would work too.  You have tagged your question `C#`.  If you are using ODP you should definitely consider leveraging its built-in support.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/win.112/e23174/featChange.htm#ODPNT0025).

This is a case where the best solution will be a matter of opinion.  You guys know your situation better than we do.  I suggest you talk it over with your team lead.  Just bear in mind that if you push for a different solution the onus will be on you to make it work; if your team lead has prior experience of implementing a trigger-based solution then that might be the safer bet.

Answer (score 0):

One possible downside of a database change notification is that of a callback from the DB to the application tier. If you have firewall rules, security zones etc, you'd usually allow flows from the application to the db tier- not the other way round which database change notification requires. So, you might be dealing with security exceptions to allow this back-flow. Looks to me like sacrificing security for performance acceleration (fewer network db queries)

Comment: well, that should not be a problem if your application is in the same local network of your DB server. But that is indeed a point to think about when your application is deployed on an external server (e.g. cloud)